# One @ in email address

Tags: javascript, validation

I want there to only be one at sign allowed in the email address and also to only contain ( a-z,A-Z, underscores (_), dot(.) and dash (-)). This is what i have so far. 
Thanks

```
var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos < 3 || dotpos < atpos + 4 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length)
{                   
    alert("You have not entered a valid Email address, please check for mistakes and re-submit");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have email addresses that contain numbers…

Comment: check this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: `<input type="email">`

Comment: Why are you banning my perfectly good email address of '@example.com

Answer (score -2):

What you want is something called a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  Basically you can specify a pattern and have javascript check your input to see if it matches that pattern.  The following javascript function should return true is the input is a valid email address, though there are a lot of topics out there that discuss which regular expression is best for this exact purpose.

```
function emailIsValid(email) { 
    var regex = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

Comment: It's much more complicated than that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: The regex can be a lot more complex, but there has to be a balance between "will it validate every single email address in the world" and "will I ever need it to be that accurate".  The regex I provided is acceptable and will work 99% of the time.  Understanding that some people would prefer a more accurate solution, however, I did point out that there are a lot of discussions on which regex is the best to use.

Comment: @Maloric yes, and that has been thoroughly discussed on SO multiple times. Which is why you are getting downvoted.